# How to calculate the power consumption in contiki

Tags: embedded, contiki, iot

In cooja simulator I the executed the power trace program for my mote and got the results

```
00:22.714   ID:1     2821 P 0.18 10 116054 604735 58865 5343 0 3699 10671 54852 5363 490 0 343 (radio 8.90% / 8.93% tx 8.16% / 8.18% listen 0.74% / 0.74%)
```

The above is the one line of my power trace program's result ,

For example if my mote is skymote , what is the values of  **ENERGEST_TYPE_CPU , ENERGEST_TYPE_LPM , ENERGEST_TYPE_LISTEN , ENERGEST_TYPE_TRANSMIT**

IN THE BELOW FORMULA how to apply the ENERGEST_TYPE_CPU , ENERGEST_TYPE_LPM , ENERGEST_TYPE_LISTEN , ENERGEST_TYPE_TRANSMIT     values in the **energest_type_time  function**

```
     energest_type_time(ENERGEST_TYPE_CPU) - last_cpu,
     energest_type_time(ENERGEST_TYPE_LPM) - last_lpm,
     energest_type_time(ENERGEST_TYPE_TRANSMIT) - last_transmit,
     energest_type_time(ENERGEST_TYPE_LISTEN) - last_listen,
     i++);
```

and i also dont' know the `last_cpu , last_lpm , last_transmit , last_listen` in the power trace result .

Answer (score 2):

The original paper is [1], but you probably want to read [2] or [3], because IMO they go into more details, especially about the accuracy.

[1] A. Dunkels, F. Osterlind, N. Tsiftes, and Z. He, “Software-based on-line energy estimation for sensor nodes,” in Proceedings of the 4th workshop on Embedded networked sensors (EmNets 2007), 2007, pp. 28–32.

[2] C. Haas, J. Wilke, and V. Stöhr, “Realistic Simulation of Energy Consumption in Wireless Sensor Networks,” in Wireless Sensor Networks, vol. 7158, no. 7158, G. Picco and W. Heinzelman, Eds. Berlin, Heidelberg: Springer, 2012, pp. 82–97.

[3] P. Hurni, B. Nyffenegger, T. Braun, and A. Hergenroeder, “On the accuracy of software-based energy estimation techniques,” in Proceedings of the 8th European Conference on Wireless Sensor Networks (EWSN 2011), 2011, pp. 49–64.

Answer (score 1):

The value of this variables shows the number of `rtimer` ticks between `ENERGEST_ON` and `ENERGEST_OFF` for different states, e.g. radio rx, tx, cpu and lpm (low power mode).

From this variables you can calculate the energy spent in those states.

**all_cpu** shows all rtime ticks in the MCU ON mode.

**all_cpu** is the result of:

```
all_cpu = energest_type_time(ENERGEST_TYPE_CPU);
```

**all_lpm** shows all rtime ticks in the low power mode.
**all_transmit** shows all rtime ticks when radio transfer data.
**all_listen** shows all rtime ticks when radio receive data.
**last_cpu** shows rtime ticks in the last cycle you printed powertrace output and the other last variables in the same manner.

Now after you get the rtime ticks in each states you can calculate the power consumed for eache mote by using cpu ticks you get from powertrace output.